# react native crashes on app open, module not found

Tags: react-native

I am not able to google for the following error. 
React native app crashes as app opens with the following error.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_js
      Process: com.zibann.littlehome.debugEug, PID: 2790
      com.facebook.jni.CppException: Exception in HostFunction: Module not found: 0

      [native code]
      v@index.android.bundle:2:1223
      d@index.android.bundle:2:866
      global code@index.android.bundle:11:4
          at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
          at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
          at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: clear your metro bundler cache?

Comment: ok.. i'm running `watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache` .. see how it goes..

Comment: @mehulmpt no difference... after clearing the cache..